# Drag and drop not working in nw.js app on windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows-10, node-webkit, nw.js

I have nw.js (webkit) desktop app with following js code

```
var holder = document.getElementById('holder');

holder.ondragover = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

holder.ondragend = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

holder.ondrop = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    handleFileSelect(event);
};
```

On windows 8 and linux, this code works, but on windows 10, it won't accept file drop. When i drag file over "holder" area, i get black circle icon.

I have tried to run app as administrator, and it don't work.
I made quick web page to try it in browser, and it works in both FF and Edge browsers.

Can someone help with this?